# How to send token ERC20 in 1 line of code on Ubuntu

Tags: ether, erc-20

I know now how to get balances of Token with `sudo geth --exec "eth.call({to: '0xad408ef944da873fe9b65f4e78e21ac2d489db90', data: '0x70a08231000000000000000000000000280e5dbe0d36be7344743ce034b104b94d930e51'})" attach`

But for sending an ERC20 token, e.g. Golem the command would be

```
sudo geth --exec "eth.call({to: '0xa74476443119A942dE498590Fe1f2454d7D4aC0d', data: '0xNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN'})" attach
```

So how to format the data part with sending address, receiving address, value, gas and gasPrice?

Answer (score 5):

To properly execute a contract method you have to encode the method signature and parameters in the data field. See:
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI

To do that from the command line you could use a command line tool to do this encoding for you. For example:
https://github.com/paritytech/ethabi

Also remember that eth.call is going to call the contract locally without creating a transaction.
If you want to post a transaction calling a contract method use:
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendtransaction